# Build details in custom section of TFS 2010 Build Summary page

Tags: build-automation

Can you help me in putting the build information in the custom section of Build Summary page.

For suppose, I would like to do some calculation on the test results, based on that I need to show the output in my custom section of Build Summary.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a VS addin:

[TFS2010 – Customizing the Build Details View – Summary View](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/08/09/tfs2010-customizing-the-build-details-view-summary-view.aspx)